# The probability of reaching distance $r>2$ starting from $2$ in a space that has a probability of escaping $x$ from the center as $\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: probability

In a continuous space the probability should be $0$. As soon as we try moving from $2$ all probabilities of escaping $2+\epsilon$ would start multiplying and we end up with $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2+\epsilon}...\frac{1}{2+k\epsilon}...$ which is $0$ for any $\epsilon$.

How about having layers that are $\epsilon > 0$ thick? It looks like the solution after $m$ layers is

$$\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2+k\epsilon}=\frac{\Gamma (\frac{2}{\epsilon})}{\Gamma (m+\frac{2}{\epsilon}) \epsilon^m}$$ and this, even without resorting to Gamma function, for $\epsilon \to 0$ obviously tends to

$$\frac{1}{2^m}$$

which means that we can escape $m$ layers with this probability, which does not help much as the layers are $0$ thick, still we *can* escape whatever it truly means. (The space in this second example is potentially discreet, that is the only difference.)

What I am trying to find is $\epsilon=f(m)$ so that if we approach $0$ using $f(m)$ we will get the constant value, constant probability meaning we do get some probability of escaping that does not depend on $m$ although the above result is interesting as well.

Either the proof that such $\epsilon=f(m)$ exists or a concrete example of the same would do.

This would be an interesting example of something like "potential" probability if it works.

Answer (score 0):

After some simpler thinking if we set $m=e^\epsilon$ we have what we wanted

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\Gamma (\frac{2}{\epsilon})}{\Gamma (e^\epsilon+\frac{2}{\epsilon}) \epsilon^{e^\epsilon}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

This is the probability of escaping one layer, which gives the same conclusion as above only in a more specific way.

So the above is indeed some sort of "potential probability".

(The conclusion that we do have $\frac{1}{2}$ already is obvious, but we wanted to show this in action of actually trying to escape. The original probability $\frac{1}{2}$ meant nothing for the point that stands there, it is meant for a point that is trying to move *through* the layer. But this now gives a meaning for the point that does not move as well - it can escape. Philosophy I know, but still... )

Similarly $$m=d^{\epsilon}$$ gives the probability $$\frac{1}{2^d}$$

Nice! :)

This is to show that the space with a defined probability of escaping has a discreet nature by this definition itself.